# React img is dangerously set inner html?

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

Here is some code I have and is giving me an error. I have no idea what the error means and why it's not displaying.

```
import React from "react";
import "./Card.css";

export default function Card() {
  return (
    <div class='card'>
        <img src='img_avatar.png' alt="Avatar" style='width:100%'> </img>
        <div class='container'>
            <h4><b>Devware</b></h4>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a space between open `<img>` and closing `</img>` tags which is invalid, also React `style` prop should be an object and `class` should be `className` as class is a reserved javascript word so your Card component should be like this

```
export default function Card() {
    return (
        <div className='card'>
            <img src='img_avatar.png' alt="Avatar" style={{ width: '100%' }} />
            <div className='container'>
                <h4><b>Devware</b></h4>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```